# to open category posts in new page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. I am using tab menu to display my category posts in my sidebar.
2. There I am using Read More link in common,I want my Read More to
   apply for my each tab(category posts) and on clicking Read More,I
   want more contents of my tab to open in new page.
3. The code I am using -

   ```
       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <!-- Do special_cat stuff... -->

       <?php the_content('more',TRUE,'');?>

       <p align="right" class="txt_caps txt_small txt_bold"><a href="#">&raquo; Read More</a></p>
   ```
4. I don't know what to use in my href="#",so that i can open my particular post in new page on tab clicked.
5. Thanks in advance.This is my first live project in Wordpress.So,I am bit new to Wordpress.Any further details,You can ask me.

Comment: Help needed regarding this.I am looking out for this from past 2 days in all forums.But,all in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new tabs are opened using `target="_blank"`
In the `href=""` just put the location you want to go to.